# Send data through JSONP and receive response

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

I am using the JSONP to send request to execute a PHP file on different domain and then receive the data from the same and then update my values.

NA

```
<script> 

$.getJSON('http://MY_URL_HERE/test_files/jsonp_response.php?callback=?','',function(res){

    console.log('Response - '+res.price_compare[0].flipkart);

  var costatflipkart = res.price_compare[0].flipkart;

  document.getElementById("flipkartCost").innerHTML = "Rs. " + costatflipkart;

});
</script>
```

I need to send data as 'price' in the JSONP request and in return my server B will fetch teh same and then trigger the callback function.

The code at ServerB is :

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . '{  
"price_compare": [
        {
            "flipkart": 2500,
        }] 

}' . ")";
```

My code is working fine so far as I send a request from ServerA to ServerB and then receive the data from Callback function, but I am still not very much sure how to sent data along with the JSONP call to the ServerB.

Comment: Just replace your second parameter in `getJSON`, the empty string, with an object of key-value pairs (`''` into `{ foo: "bar", baz: 2500 }`).

Comment: That was quite helpful. Thanks for your time!